# PHP: Почему foreach ($x as $key => $value) не хочет "расчехлять" массив?

Tags: php, массивы, foreach, phpquery, substring

Спарсил все заголовки сайта с помощью библиотеки PHP Query.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Два массива array(331) содержат строки с заголовками.
Пытаюсь вывести их циклом с обрезкой точки маркировочного списка. Вот так:

```
require_once ('phpQuery-onefile.php');
$url = 'https://www.englishforcing.ru/o-nas/karta-sajta/';
$file = file_get_contents($url);
    preg_match_all('|<li class="wsp-post">(.+)</li>|', $file, $matches);

foreach ($matches as $key => $value) {
       var_dump(substr($value, 1));
}
```

Интерпретатор выводит мне ошибку: Warning: substr() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in W:\domains\localhost\par.php on line 12

Не пойму, почему $key => $value не раскрыл массив до строк.

Если делаю проверку на тип:

```
foreach ($matches as $key => $value) {
    if (is_string($value)) {
        var_dump(substr($value, 1));
    }
}
```

Получаю просто пустую страницу.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как добраться до значений в цикле foreach и обрезать таки "несчастные" точки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что изначально в массиве `$matches` нужные Вам элементы находятся в массиве с индексом `0`. Поэтому нужно обращаться к нулевому индексу. То есть, не `$matches`, а `$matches[0]`.

Попробуйте так:

```
require_once ('phpQuery-onefile.php');
$url = 'https://www.englishforcing.ru/o-nas/karta-sajta/';
$file = file_get_contents($url);
preg_match_all('|<li class="wsp-post">(.+)</li>|', $file, $matches);

foreach ($matches[0] as $key => $value) {
       var_dump(substr($value, 1));
}
```

Я получил массив с нужными элементами.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое LexXy

Comment: На здоровье )))